# backbone nested collections in model listening for add

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I have a model that has collections within it. Within my web app I have a project model, and in that I have an attribute called "collaborators" this attribute is actually a collection of users.

In the initialize of my view I have the following,

`this.model.get('collaborators').on( 'change', alert("!!"), this);`

When the view firsts loads I get an alert, firther into the view I have an event, that fires the following,

```
var newModel = new app.User({ id: this.clickedElement.data('userId') });
                console.log(this.model.get(this.formSection)); // shows that the collection has 4 models
                newModel.fetch({
                    success: function() {

                        that.model.get(that.formSection).add(newModel);
                        console.log(that.model.get(that.formSection)); //shows that the collection has 5 models

                    }

                });
```

As you can see in the code above, I am logging my collaborators collection and it shows a length of 4, after the fetch in the success method, am I adding the model I just fetched to that collection, and then logging the collection again, this time it returns a length of 5.

This to me means that the add is successful, so is the event listener for "add" not firing after the initial page view?

Comment: I don't see an `add` listener.. Only a `change` - but that's on your collaborators collection. Collections don't fire `change` events and I'm not sure if it'll bubble up to the parent model.

Comment: Even if I do `this.model.get('collaborators').on('add', alert("!!"), this);' It still only fires on the initial load of the view, and not when I add further data to the collection.

Comment: Have you tried using only the `change` event on the parent model?

Comment: yep `this.listenTo('this.model', 'change', alert("!!"));` does exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that you should pass some function as a second argument of `on` method. But you're firing `alert` right at the event binding moment and passing `alert`'s result instead of function.
This should work correctly:

```
this.model.get('collaborators').on('change', function(){
    alert("!!");
});
```

**Update:** But you should clarify which events you want to catch. You can find all events fired during fetching (or any other process) by launching search for `trigger` method calls across backbone.js file.

**Update:** Also you can use this code to catch all of events fired:

```
collaborators.on('all', function(){
    /**
     * `arguments` object contains all of arguments passed to the function.
     * @see http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on for more details about `all`
     * catching.
     */
    console.log(arguments); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you binding to the collaborators' change event, you should use Backbone's listenTo event.

```
this.listenTo(this.model.get('collaborators'), "change", function(){alert("!!"), this);
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo

The advantage of using this.listenTo is when the view gets closed/removed, Backbone will automatically invoke this.stopListening causing your view to automatically unbind the event. This will help you clean up events and prevent phantom views.

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-stopListening